# plot predict.lm result with confidence intervals

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I have a df which is an output of `predict.lm` appended to another df with two columns `label` and `actual`

```
df <- data.frame(
label = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'), 
actual = c(13.9, 13.4, 13.8, 14.3, 14.2, 13.6, 14.1),
fit = c(13.8, 13.9, 14.1, 14.0, 13.9, 14.3, 14.1),
lwr = c(13.6, 13.7, 13.8, 13.8, 13.7, 14.0, 13.9),
upr = c(14.3, 14.2, 14.7, 14.3, 14.1, 14.9, 14.9)
)
```

I want to plot `actual` vs `fit` where `lwr` and `upr` are shown similar to this figure below without the line, and the dots are either colour or pattern based on `label` column.
This figure is an example of how I want my figure looks like. x and y are not from my data.
[image: plot]

Comment: We also need x to make the plot.

Comment: Please post your data in an easy-to-paste form.

Comment: @G5W x = actual, y = fit

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman If x = actual,  then why are your x values 13.4-14.6 but the labels on the x axis are 0.1 - 0.6?  Isn't actual the y-value for the black points?

Comment: @G5W, this is not the figure from my data, it is an example. I want my figure looks like this in term of shape of the confidence interval (upr and lwr)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik you can easily copy=paste the df now

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman Did you mean to have two points with actual = 13.9?

Comment: @G5W it happens, but I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  label = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'), 
  actual = c(13.9, 13.4, 13.8, 14.3, 14.2, 13.6, 14.1),
  fit = c(13.8, 13.9, 14.1, 14.0, 13.9, 14.3, 14.1),
  lwr = c(13.6, 13.7, 13.8, 13.8, 13.7, 14.0, 13.9),
  upr = c(14.3, 14.2, 14.7, 14.3, 14.1, 14.9, 14.9)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = actual, y = fit)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(color = label))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just plot the line with `plot` and then create the shaded region with `polygon`.

```
ORD = order(df$actual)
plot(df[ORD, 2:3],type="l", ylim=c(min(df$lwr), max(df$upr)), col="blue")
polygon(c(df$actual[ORD], df$actual[rev(ORD)]), border=NA,
    c(df$upr[ORD], df$lwr[rev(ORD)]), col="#88888844")
```

[image: Plot with error limits]

If you want a smoother version,  you could use splines.

```
## Smoothed version
plot(spline(df[ORD, 2:3]), type="l", 
    ylim=c(min(df$lwr), max(df$upr)), col="blue")

UpperFun = splinefun(df[ORD, c(2,5)])
LowerFun = splinefun(df[ORD, c(2,4)])
ACT      = seq(min(df$actual), max(df$actual), 0.02)
UPP      = UpperFun(ACT)
LOW      = LowerFun(ACT)

polygon( c(ACT, rev(ACT)), c(UPP, rev(LOW)), 
    border=NA, col="#88888844")
```

[image: Smoothed curve]